QGIS Value Map/Value Relation: How can I set up several interdependent selection windows during digitization?
When digitizing objects, I would like to be able to select several categories and, depending on this, several subcategories in a multiple-choice form.
Using the Value Map and Value Relation widgets, I have at least managed to select a single main category and any number of associated sub-categories for my objects.
How can I achieve this?
